# How to animate a text cutout over a background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to imitate the animation shown below using CSS and/or JavaScript. I have created the beginning step but cannot figure out how to animate the zooming in part.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #222;
    }
    .container {
      background-image: url(test.jpg);
      height: 96vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .box {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 98vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .big {
      font-size: 17vw;
      background: url(http://viralsweep.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/unsplash.jpg) 33px 659px;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      padding-top: 24vh;
      margin-top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      animation: opac 2s infinite;
    }
@keyframes opac {
  0%, 100% {
    /*rest the move*/

  }
  50% {
  /*move some distance in y position*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1 class="big">TRY THIS</h1>
  </div>
  <!--end of box-->
</div>
<!--end of conatiner-->
```

And my **TARGET:** 
[image]

Comment: Well, this is not trouble shooting. I am afraid what you're asking for is *too much* although you have provided a valid attempt. I will give this a shot, but no promises since this question could be closed.

Comment: Can you name a credible/official source for the code you're asking? Even an example of such a source in general, no matter, if just this kind of a code wouldn't be available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came up with a solution based on your original code using `-webkit-text-fill-color` and `-webkit-background-clip-text` and added `font-size` and a negative `text-indent` for the animation. The negative `text-indent` is needed to keep the text "centered" within the element because text within elements always wants to bump up against the left edge.

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #container {
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
  }

  #image {
    animation: scale 3000ms linear infinite;
    background: url(http://viralsweep.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/unsplash.jpg);
    bottom: 0;
    font: 96px "Arial";
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }

  @keyframes scale {
    0% {
      font-size: 66px;
      text-indent: 0;
    }
    16% {
      font-size: 132px;
      text-indent: 0;
    }
    80% {
      font-size: 330px;
      text-indent: -500px;
    }
    100% {
      font-size: 10000px;
      text-indent: -25300px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image">try this</div>
</div>
```

Basically, I'm adjusting the `text-indent` so that as the font-size increases the middle "T" stays centered (it's really not in the center though) and then the text becomes so big (10,000 pixels!) that the "T" does the "reveal" effect by filling the space.

Comment: FYI, you can avoid `-webkit-text-fill-color` by just using `color` instead. `background-clip-text` also has a non-prefixed version that works in Firefox.

Answer (score 14):

A posibility, using 2 elements, one for the image and another for the text, and blend mode to achieve transparency:

Note that blend mode is not supported by IE or Edge

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/600);
  background-size: cover;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;

}

.big {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: black;
  animation: zoom 4s infinite;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4, 4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="big">TRY THIS</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i want the box behind the text. Actually there will be three layers one is background image '.container', 2nd '.box' with white background and '.big'with transparent. is this possible?

Comment: Please note that `mix-blend-mode` is not supported in IE\Edge. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode

Answer (score 8):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("https://www.viralsweep.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  animation: 2s scale cubic-bezier(0.88, 0, 1, 0.1) infinite;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translateX(-0.3em);
  font: bold 7vw "Arial", sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@keyframes scale {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(500);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="text">TRY THIS</div>
  </div>
</div>
```